# How to store my data (C#.net)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, c#-4.0

I'm having a bit of a problem deciding how to store some data. To see it from a simple perspective, it will be a simple table of data but there will be many tables. There will be about 7 columns in each table, but again there will be a lot of tables (and they will be created at runtime, whenever the customer wants a clean grid)

The data has to be stored locally in a file (and there will not be multiple instances of the software running).

I'm using C# 4.0 and I have been looking at using XML files(one file per table, or storing multiple tables in a file), sqlite, sql server CE, access etc. I will be happy if someone here has some comments or suggestions on how to do/not to do. Stability and reliability(e.g. no trashed databases because of unstable third party software) is probably my biggest concern.

Comment: How large will this data be? Can it fit in-memory? Is it required to perform extensive queries on it or it will be a single load/save? Do other programs/processes are expected to access/modify this data? A minimal set of questions that need answers before picking the right tool. Every answer without providing more information would be pure speculation.

Comment: One big piece of info I think you left out was how many rows are you looking at per table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML wont be a good choice if you are planning to make several queries, since loading text files may be painful when they grow (talking about files over 1mb). If you plan to mantain the data low, the xml would be good to keep it simple. I still won't use it, but if you have a background, then the benefits will be heavier than the learning curve.

If you have no expertise in any of them, and the data is light my suggestion is SQLite, I beleive is the best lightweight DB for .Net and the prvider is very good. you can find it easily on Google.

I would tell you that Access is not recommendable, but this is a personal oppinion. Many people use it and I think is for some reason. So you should check it out and try it.

Again, my final recommendation is SQLite, unless you know very well another one, in which case you'll have to think how much your data is going to grow. If you plan to have a DB around 100mb, any of them, except xml would do; If you think it'll grow bigger than that, consider SQLite heavily

Comment: The size could be a problem if i store the data in a single XML file, but not if i store it in multiple. But there are advantages of keeping everything in a single file. I have experience with xml (at least a little, i have been using it with LINQ on previous projects)  and mysql + microsoft sql server for some other projects. As I see it access has the advantage that I don't have to rely on 3rd party code whereas with SQLite i'll need an adapter from a 3rd party, which i'm a bit worried about. But it seems like there is a few open source solutions so it might not be a problem anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to store the data locally in a file, I would recommend the sqlite option since it seems your data is created in the form of a database table already.  Sqlite is already built to handle multiple tables and columns so it means less mental overhead for you, the developer.

http://web.archive.org/web/20100208133236/http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/ is a decent tutorial to give a quick overview on how to set it up and get going.

As for what NOT to do: don't try to make your own scheme to save the data to a file, it's a well understood problem that has been solved many times over, why re-invent the wheel?